# Unicode output for bit datatype in mysql

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, unicode

Have a mysql table customer with a field check:

```
mysql> desc customer;
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| check              | bit(1)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

when I query, boolean datatype output in ubuntu command prompt, it shows up as a unicode character like this:

[image]

Is this env specific? How to solve it, would like to see it as 0/1 or true/false?

Comment: I’m afraid you would have to do that directly in your query, using an IF or similar. Might perhaps make more sense to switch to a TINYINT, or ENUM (if you need to ensure the only two possible values are 0 and 1 directly on a database level, which TINYINT would not do.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That symbol means the field is **`true`**. If **`false`** it will look empty. All possible values below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No problem.

That box with `0001` in it is saying that the character is hex `0001` and that there is no graphic for it.  MySQL will treat it as "true", just as it treats these as true:

```
TRUE (but not the string 'TRUE')
true
1
'1'
123456789
-99
```

You can check by saying

```
SELECT IF(agreed_tos, 'agreed', 'did not') FROM customer;
```

Meanwhile, do you really need it to be tri-valued?  That is, shouldn't the column be declared `NOT NULL`:

Comment: tri-value *not* required, it was only a test table.